# If element is in viewport- stop scroll animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, sliding

Hi I followed a tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/

It is working just fine, however, when an element is already in viewport (like if the browser is small and the page is loaded), then the jQuery doesn't add the CLASS to transition until AFTER scroll.

Is there a way to check if an element is already in viewport on load and then add a class of 'already-viewed?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var viewed = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("body *")
             , function (el, i) {
                return (el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight 
                    && el.getBoundingClientRect().left <= window.innerWidth) 
                    && $(el).addClass("already-viewed") && el
             }).filter(Boolean);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var body = $("body");
    $.each(new Array(180), function () {
        body.append(
        $("<img>"))
    });
    
    var viewed = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("body *"), function (el, i) {
        return (el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight 
               && el.getBoundingClientRect().left <= window.innerWidth) 
               && $(el).addClass("already-viewed") && el
    }).filter(Boolean);
    body
    .append("total images: " + $("img").length 
                + ", already viewed: " + $(".already-viewed").length);
    console.log(viewed.length, $(viewed))
});
```

```css
body {
    width : 1000px;
    height : 1000px;
}
img {
    width : 50px;
    height : 50px;
    background : navy;
}
.already-viewed {
    outline:0.15em solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks..It's giving almost everything in the body the class .already-viewed so it's taking some classes away- messing up my css.. any ideas?

Comment: Hi sorry, it was working for a sec, then I deleted unnecessary JS files and now all elements are getting 'already-viewed' class. This is the website I'm working on: www.ranchosanvalentin.com. The element has a class of "animBlock" if this block is already in view, then it should get the "already-viewed" class added to it. Because right now, if it's in view it won't appear on screen until you SCROLL

Comment: If possible , can create "stacksnippets" http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Tried changing selector to `document.querySelectorAll("animBlock")` ?

Comment: Yes! that helped! But it removes the other class on that div. Any way on how to ADD class (not remove). Thank you so much!

Comment: Try substituting `$(el).addClass("already-viewed")` for `!el.setAttribute("class", "already-viewed")` ; see updated post