# Detecting Animation Elements in View

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to an element when it is in the viewport. I have achieved this however it causes serious issues to the performance of my site when I scroll.

I currently have this JavaScript:

```
//Cache reference to window and animation items
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);

$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');

function check_if_in_view() {
var window_height = $window.height();
var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

$.each($animation_elements, function() {
var $element = $(this);
var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);

//check to see if this current container is within viewport
if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
    (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
  $element.addClass('in-view');
} else {
  $element.removeClass('in-view');
}
});
}
```

So as you can see the `check_if_in_view()` function seems to be constantly firing as the page is being scrolled and I believe this might be the reason why the performance might be so bad.

Is there a more efficient way of adding a class when scrolling the page that wont cause performance issues on my site?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397804/if-element-is-in-viewport-stop-scroll-animation

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` to delay calling the function every time a `scroll` event is fired. In the following code (which I borrowed [from Codrops](https://github.com/codrops/OnScrollEffectLayout)), a flag is set to call the function every 60 milliseconds in the case of continous scrolling.

```
function Scroller(el) { 
    this.elements = Array.prototype.slice.call( el );
    this._init();
}

Scroller.prototype = {
    _init : function() {
        //this flag prevents that the function _scrollPage is called 
        //every time the 'scroll' event is fired
        this.didScroll = false;
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', this._scrollHandler.bind(this), false );
    },
    _scrollHandler : function() {
        if( !this.didScroll ) {
            this.didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( function() { this._scrollPage(); }, 60 );
        }
    },
    _scrollPage : function() {

        this.elements.forEach( function( el, i ) {
            if( inViewport(el) ) {
                classie.add( el, 'i-am-in-the-viewport' );
            }
            else {

                classie.remove( el, 'i-am-in-the-viewport' );
            }
        });
        this.didScroll = false;
    }
};
```

To use it call `new Scroller( document.getElementsByClassName('elements-to-watch') );`.

Check out the complete code on Codrops to see the implementation of the `inViewPort()` function. [Classie.js](https://github.com/desandro/classie) is used to handle the assignation of class names.

Don't be afraid to ask for clarification if there's something you don't get!