# jQuery : Get All DOM elements come under the selected part (Rectangle) like zooming plugins of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want all the DOM elements (which can be overlapped by others too) to be listed out which falls under the selection. The thing I tried giving me at a fixed coordinate (with overlapped ones) but I need it to give me for full rectangle.

https://jsfiddle.net/mantrig/3tqqy0gt/

```
var flag=0;
$("#enable-show").click(function(){

    if(flag==0) {
        $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
            $('#tail').css({
                left:  e.pageX - 80,
                top:   e.pageY-50,
            });
            var $elements = GetAllElementsAt( e.pageX , e.pageY);
            var html="";
            $elements.each(function() {

                html +=  $(this)[0].id + "<br />";
                $("#result").html(html);

            });
            $("#tail").show();

        });
        flag++;
    }
    else {

        $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){

            $("#tail").hide();
        });
        flag=0;
    }
});

function GetAllElementsAt(x, y) {
    var $elements = $("body *").map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var l = offset.left;
        var t = offset.top;
        var h = $this.height();
        var w = $this.width();

        var maxx = l + w;
        var maxy = t + h;

        $("ul").append("<li>" + $this[0].id + " (" + $this[0].tagName + ")" + " [l:=" + l + ",t:=" + t + ",h:=" + h + ",w:=" + w + ",maxx:=" + maxx + ",maxy:=" + maxy + "]</li>");

        return (y <= maxy && y >= t) && (x <= maxx && x >= l) ? $this : null;
    });

    return $elements;
}
```

Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Talking about finding elements at position, you could use `document.getElementsAtPosition(x, y)`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev actully I don't want at given position. It is a rectangular select box so whatever DOM elements falling into that rectangle I need them all. if you can check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mantrig/3tqqy0gt/1/

Comment: Try using `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` , see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28397804/

Comment: @guest271314 thanks!! But this thing will get me the position of my rect on screen, how I'll get all other DOM elements which is under that whole Rectangle that's my query. Getting the position I've already done using mouse coordinate if you can check my fiddle (link is in above comment).

Comment: You're looking for AABB, see this link for simple collision detection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection.

Comment: @GovindMantri _"how I'll get all other DOM elements which is under that whole Rectangle"_ Loop through all `DOM` elements to check if their position is within rectangle position at mouse event

Comment: @guest271314 hmmm that can be one solution but I'm not sure about performance coz my webpage contains svg with thousands of DOM elements. Can you share any thread how exactly this thing is done or How these zoom on image thing works (that would be exactly same for my case). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JoshHarrison not exactly!! I need all elements weather it is colliding or not the only condition is it should come under my rectangular selection. To be exact I'm looking for something which can replace  'getElementsAtPosition(x,y)' to 'getAllElementsAtArea(x,y,width,height)' .