# Understanding getBoundingClientRect for elements outside of viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, getboundingclientrect

I have a horizontal scroll bar as you can see here...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxxEQb

It works pretty well apart from the fact that you can scroll to the right indefinitely.

In order to limit the right-scroll (so that you can't keep scrolling right when there's no more items), I want to detect when the last button (id=lastButton) is further to the left than the link to scroll right (id=goRightLink).

I've added these couple of console outputs to the codepen so you can follow what I'm seeing...

```
console.log("right of go-right-link: " + $("#goRightLink")[0].getBoundingClientRect().right);

console.log("right of lastButton: " + $("#lastButton")[0].getBoundingClientRect().right);
```

I can't make any sense of the numbers - when I scroll far enough to the right for the final button (button 30) to be visible, I can the values "go-right-link: 1389, lastButton: 1313" (which is great), but if I scroll a little back to the left so that the button 30 is now off screen, I can the values "go-right-link: 1246, lastButton: 1389".  Then even weirder, I scroll a little left again and get a negative value for lastButton (-549).

Instead of painfully describing that further here, it's probably easier to use the console output in the codepen to see how the numbers change as Button 30 is coming in and out of view.

All I'm trying to do is establish some kind of pattern in the numbers that will tell me when I should prevent any further scroll-rights (i.e. when button 30 is visible).

Hugely appreciate any thoughts at all!

---

### ------EDIT-------

I found a secondary solution to this (which I'm not posting as an answer since it doesn't answer the question relating to understanding getBoundingClientRect()).  I ended up simply summing all the buttons within the ul (which would give width regardless of whether it was on/off screen)...

```
var widthOfAllTagLis=0;
          $("#tagUl li button").each(
                                    function() {
                                      widthOfAllTagLis = widthOfAllTagLis + $(this).outerWidth(true); //passing true includes margins (as well as padding)
                                    });
```

And then adding this check before any transitions to the right...

```
if ($("#tagUl").width() + 5 < widthOfAllTagLis) { //perform transition 
} else {
//don't perform transition because we can already see all the buttons
}
```

This only works because the result of $("#tagUl").width() changes as the margin-left property changes (something I wasn't expecting!)

Answer (score 0):

Try including `if` condition to check if `.tagUlContainer` `width` plus combined `a` elements `width` plus `#tagUL` `margin-left`, which would be an increasing negative value, is greater than `0`

```
var tags = $("#tagUl"),
  w = parseInt(tags.find("li").css("width")) * tags.find("li").length;

function scrollTags(direction) {
  console.log(w + (parseInt(tags.css("marginLeft"))) + 200
             , tags.parent().width());
    if (direction == "right") {
      if (w + (parseInt(tags.css("marginLeft"))) + 200 >
          tags.parent().width()) {
        tags.animate({
          marginLeft: "-=200"
        }, "fast");
      }

    } else {
      if (parseInt(tags.css('marginLeft')) < 0) {
        tags.animate({
          marginLeft: "+=200"
        }, "fast");
      }
    }
}
```

codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxRJqK

See also [If element is in viewport- stop scroll animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397804/if-element-is-in-viewport-stop-scroll-animation/)

Comment: thanks guest271314 - that kinda works, but what's the significance of 1200?  For example, if I shrink the screen size this won't work as well, and if I expand fully there'll still be some superfluous scrolling.  Also, just a point, but I had to move your if-statement inside the "if (direction=="right)" check or it prevented scrolling left as well.

Comment: @d3wannabe _"what's the significance of 1200?"_ If open `console` and inspect `#tagUL`  when last `li` is to left of "right" button, parent element `#tagUL` `margin-left` is less than `-1200` . _"Also, just a point, but I had to move your if-statement inside the "if (direction=="right)" check or it prevented scrolling left as well"_ Can post link to updated codepen ?

Comment: But the threshold value changes based on how many buttons there are and how much you've shrunk/expanded the page.  I don't think you can really rely on a static value given those 2 variables?  Here's the forked codepen that allows scrolling left: http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/pgEGXj

Comment: @d3wannabe  See updated post, adjusted `if` condition to `(parseInt($(".tagUlContainer").css("width")) + parseInt($("#tagUl").css("marginLeft"))) > 0`

Comment: @d3wannabe See updated post, added `+50` for `a` elements combined `width`

Comment: guest271314 - your codepen doesn't work properly - on a full size window (around 1200 pixels) you can scroll a few times past the last button (Button 30).  And on a minimised window (around 600 pixels) you can't even scroll as far as Button 30 (i.e. you can never get to see it)