# How to find elements id's which are in view port using java script and angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an HTML page with vertical scroll bar. i need to get the elements ids which are present in view port (visible part of HTML) using java script and angular js.

Comment: See [If element is in viewport- stop scroll animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397804/if-element-is-in-viewport-stop-scroll-animation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method of each node you want to test and then test to see if it is within the viewport bounds. There's a library that does this already, here's how they do it:

https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport/blob/master/src/index.js#L70

Answer (score 0):

You can take a more primitive approach by simply comparing the distance of an element from the top of the page to the current vertical position of the scrollbar. You'll also have to compare the scroll position to the distance from the top plus the height of the element.

If you're open to using jQuery, check this out: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop1